# Writing a login screen like default android pattern lock

Tags: android

I want to write a login screen for my new app like android's default pattern lock. Is there a way to do this? Is there any library to help doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be, I would start with [Gestures.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html)

Comment: I found this: http://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern and now I am trying to utilize this.